# Encoding confusion in editor, entering characters, recieving utf-8 in literal

Tags: r, encoding, pycharm

In the editor (PyCharm with R plugin) I enter: `x <- 'ů'`, when I read the content of `x`, it, however, gives me `"\xf9"`

At the same time `x == 'ů'` gives me `FALSE`. What might be wrong and how to fix it?